# Magento 2:"TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Test\HelloMagento\Plugin\ExamplePlugin::beforeSetTitle()

Tags: magento2, before-plugin

**di.xml**

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Test\HelloMagento\Controller\Index\Example">
        <plugin name="Test_HelloMagento_Plugin" type="Test\HelloMagento\Plugin\ExamplePlugin"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

**ExamplePlugin.php**

```
namespace Test\HelloMagento\Plugin;

class ExamplePlugin 
{

    public function beforeSetTitle(Test\HelloMagento\Controller\Index\Example $subject, $title)
    {
        $title = $title . " to ";
        echo __METHOD__ . "</br>";

        return [$title];
    }}
```

**Example.php**

```
<?php

namespace Test\HelloMagento\Controller\Index;

class Example extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $title;

    public function execute()
    {
        echo $this->setTitle('Welcome Plugin example');
        echo $this->getTitle();
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        return $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

Im getting the below error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Test\HelloMagento\Plugin\ExamplePlugin::beforeSetTitle() must be an
>   instance of
>   Test\HelloMagento\Plugin\Test\HelloMagento\Controller\Index\Example,
>   instance of Test\HelloMagento\Controller\Index\Example\Interceptor
>   given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php
>   on line 123 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\Test\HelloMagento\Plugin\ExamplePlugin.php:8

I am a beginner. Please help.

Comment: clear your `var/generation` and `cache`. and try.

Comment: put a backslash ( \ ) before class test like \Test\HelloMagento\Controller\Index\Example $subject

Comment: Thanks Rizwan and Ramkishan. :) i added and backslash and cleared var/gen and cache. It worked.